# How can I separate information into fields in both input and output?

Tags: bash, awk, stat

```
$ stat -c "%Y#%n#%y" *  | awk -F'#' "BEGIN {OFS=\"|\"} NR==1,NR==3 {print \$2 \$3}"
directory1/Blum2017-12-22 22:33:38.644178442 -0500
dir2/Ciolli2017-12-22 21:53:51.769368496 -0500
Dar2017-12-06 13:29:37.698296879 -0500
```

I try to set up input and output field separators.

- I use `#` as input separator, but a filename can contains `#`. Is there a better choice? I don't know if `stat` can separate the output pathnames by `/null` as `find` does and if `awk` can accept input field separator `\null`.
- why does my setup of `OFS` to `|` not work?

Thanks.

Comment: (1) it depends - what are you trying to do, exactly? (2) because `\$2 \$3` is a string concatenation: try `\$2,\$3`

Comment: Thanks. (1) I want to make sure the three pieces of information provided by `stat` are recognzed by awk as separate fields.

Comment: It seems the use of null is problematic: see [this insightful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19229243/7659430).

Answer (score 1):

```
stat -c "%Y/%n/%y" * | awk -F'/' 'NR==1,NR==3 {print $2"|"$3}'
```

Or:

```
stat -c "%Y/%n/%y" * | awk -F'/' 'BEGIN {OFS="|"} NR==1,NR==3 {print $2,$3}'
```

**Explanation:**

Instead of `#`, you might want to use `/` (the directory separator), since it can not be part of a filename.

The input `awk` field separator needs to be set accordingly: `-F'/'`.

As already pointed out in a comment by [@steeldriver](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/65304/steeldriver), you have two ways of choosing an output field separator.

1. Use string concatenation: `print $2"|"$3`.
2. Define `OFS="|"` and then `print $2,$3`.

I chose single quotes `'` over double quotes `"` which reduces the need of escaping in this case.

**Update:**

Since the question now specifies that the `stat` output may contain the directory separator, `/` would not be a wise choice for the record separator. The only other character that I know of which is not allowed in filenames is `NUL`, but its use is problematic at least in this case. My suggestion would be to make up an awkward string that is very unlikely (although allowed) to be found as part of a filename. Accidentally, `\x0` (which is a representation of `NUL`) could be a good choice:

```
stat -c "%Y\x0%n\x0%y" * | awk -F\x0 'BEGIN {OFS="|"} NR==1,NR==3 {print $2"|"$3}'
```

Comment: Thanks. The output of `stat` can be pathnames containing `/`, because there can be subdirectories in the expansion of `*`.

Comment: @Tim Your best bet is to use the NUL character then!

Comment: How shall I specify NUL to `stat` and `awk`?

Comment: I don't think it will work. You can specify a very awkward string that is unlikely to be found in filenames, such as `#°°#`.